# Oracle : How to join 2 tables by one value from fist table with another table where condition value

Tags: sql, oracle

Dear Everyone have experience,

I have 2 tables try to join with condition. First table . Employee Table :   `select emp_id, emp_code, section_id, party_id, admin_type from employee`

```
ID | Emp_Code | Section_ID | Party_ID | Admin_Type
1  | emp01    | sec01      | part01   | Null
2  | emp02    | sec01      | part01   | Null
3  | emp03    | sec02      | part02   | Null
4  | emp04    | sec01      | part01   | A
5  | emp05    | sec02      | part02   | B
6  | emp06    | sec01      | part01   | C
```

The second table is group of Admin

```
ID | Admin_Type | Group
1  | A          | 1
2  | B          | 2
3  | C          | 1
```

On the data is complex and many values so I Try to join with condition in each emp by matching
section_id and party_id in each emp_code (fix value into where clause).

```
select g.admin_type, g.group, e.emp_code as Admin from group_admin as g
left join employee e on e.admin_type = g.admin_type
where e.section_id in (select section_id from employee where emp_code = 'emp01')
and e.party_id = (select party_id from employee where emp_code = 'emp01')
and g.group = '1' and admin_type is not null;
```

result above query is Admin of emp_code = emp01' like table below

```
Admin_Type | Group | Admin
A          | 1     | emp04
C          | 1     | emp06
```

I try to build oracle stored procedure by draw a table for all emp_code join with empcode with have admin_code only same section_id and party_id like below.

```
Emp_Code |  Section_ID | Party_ID | Admin_Type  --- | Admin  | Group | Admin_Type
emp01    |  sec01      | part01   | NULL        --- | emp04 | 1     | A
emp01    |  sec01      | part01   | NULL        --- | emp06 | 1     | C
emp02    |  sec01      | part01   | NULL        --- | emp04 | 1     | A
emp02    |  sec01      | part01   | NULL        --- | emp06 | 1     | C
emp03    |  sec02      | part02   | NULL        --- | emp05 | 1     | B
```

Comment: There is no question here. What is the question you are asking?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My quesion is try to write sql join with same section_id and party_id like last table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this are you joining to section type and admin code when those exist in the employee table

The table that is the result of this query

```
SELECT EmpCode, Section_ID, Admin_Type 
FROM employee
WHERE Admin_Type is not null
```

So just join to that:

```
SELECT e.Emp_Code, e.Section_ID, e.Party_ID, e.Admin_Type, sub.Admin, sub.Group, sub.Admin_Type
FROM employee as E
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT EmpCode as Admin, Group, Section_ID, Admin_Type 
  FROM employee
  WHERE Admin_Type is not null
) sub ON sub.Section_ID = e.Section_ID
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan for the idea of existing relation is Section and Party and for the full query I find it so I have one or two table for map the group of Admin but it's not problem.

Comment: @HKjens -- if this solved your problem you should up-vote it and mark it as the solution with the check mark.

Comment: Ok but my reputation cannot reach that task vote then I try up my level.